# Attaching events to an TextBox underlying for a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

Is there any way to get underlying control for a DataGridView cell?
I would like to attach normal texbox events to capture keystrokes and capture value changed.

So i have 4 columns, each of them contains number of cells and all cells in one row should be handled different way based on its type.

Basically i need my events to be fired only when a cell is being edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subscribe the `DataGridView.EditingControlShowing` event, then subscribe the `TextBox` event you need.

---

Example with `TextBox.KeyDown` :

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var txtBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (txtBox != null)
    {
        // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid 
        // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
        txtBox.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(underlyingTextBox_KeyDown);

        // Add the event handler. 
        txtBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(underlyingTextBox_KeyDown);
    }
}

void underlyingTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now the code is more correct, because it follows the suggestion given on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx):

> The DataGridView control hosts one
>   editing control at a time, and reuses
>   the editing control whenever the cell
>   type does not change between edits.
>   When attaching event-handlers to the
>   editing control, you must therefore
>   take precautions to avoid attaching
>   the same handler multiple times. To
>   avoid this problem, remove the handler
>   from the event before you attach the
>   handler to the event. This will
>   prevent duplication if the handler is
>   already attached to the event, but
>   will have no effect otherwise. For
>   more information, see the example code
>   in the
>   DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl
>   class overview.

**EDIT 2:**

As per comment:

`TextChanged` event is called before `EditingControlShowing`, and then again after it.

You can distinguish between the two calls using this trick:

```
void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (txtBox.Focused)
    {
        // second call (after EditingControlShowing) the TextBox is focused
    }
    else
    {
        // first call (before EditingControlShowing) the TextBox is not focused
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one question - if handler is added this way how will it act when the cell will be focused couple of times? DO i need to clear that event somehow?

Comment: @Random: Check my edit. Now the event subscription/unsubscription is handled as suggested on MSDN ;)

Comment: @digEmAll - there is one "feature" regarding calling events. Event TextChanged is fired before EditingControlShowing which when combined with what MSDN is talking about will result in calling TextChanged event handled for a target cell (one that will got focus soon) by an event handler registered for cell you try to leave... Strange...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @digEmAll I was able to register events to an underlying TextBox however there is very strange events handling for that approach and some precautions must be taken.

I've noticed that TextChanged event for new cell text box was fired before EditingControlShowing. It results with firing handler registered originally for the cell just being leave with field that will be focused as the sender. That's why all events should be deregistered on leave to avoid that behavior.

Final working solution for my problem:

```
    void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Control is TextBox)
        {

            DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
            DataGridViewColumn dgvCol= dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn;

            TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;

            foreach (cFieldLayoutType fieldLayout in FieldLayouts)
            {

                string context = dgvCol.Name.Substring(dgvCol.Name.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

                if (context == fieldLayout.columnName)
                {
                    //See URL to check why it is done this way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx

                    KeyPressEventHandler kpehAmount = new KeyPressEventHandler(oTextBoxAmount_KeyPress);                        
                    KeyPressEventHandler kpehDecimal = new KeyPressEventHandler(oTextBoxDecimal_KeyPress);
                    KeyPressEventHandler kpehDate = new KeyPressEventHandler(oTextBoxDate_KeyPress);
                    EventHandler textChangedHandlerAmount = new EventHandler(oTextBoxAmount_TextChanged);

                    tb.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox_DeregisterCellEventsOnLeave);                        
                    switch (fieldLayout.Type)
                    {
                        case cFieldType.amount:
                            {
                                tb.KeyPress += kpehAmount;

                                tb.TextChanged += textChangedHandlerAmount;
                                break;
                            }
                        case cFieldType.numeric:
                            {
                                tb.KeyPress += kpehDecimal;
                                break;
                            }
                        case cFieldType.date:
                            {
                                tb.KeyPress += kpehDate;
                                break;
                            }
                        case cFieldType.text:
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void textBox_DeregisterCellEventsOnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        KeyPressEventHandler kpehAmount = new KeyPressEventHandler(oTextBoxAmount_KeyPress);
        KeyPressEventHandler kpehDecimal = new KeyPressEventHandler(oTextBoxDecimal_KeyPress);
        KeyPressEventHandler kpehDate = new KeyPressEventHandler(oTextBoxDate_KeyPress);
        EventHandler textChangedHandlerAmount = new EventHandler(oTextBoxAmount_TextChanged);
        EventHandler textBoxDeregisterOnLeave = new EventHandler(textBox_DeregisterCellEventsOnLeave);

        tb.KeyPress -= kpehAmount;
        tb.KeyPress -= kpehDate;
        tb.KeyPress -= kpehDecimal;
        tb.TextChanged -= textChangedHandlerAmount;
        tb.Leave -= textBoxDeregisterOnLeave;       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the **EditingControlShowing** event

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                (e.Control as TextBox).KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
                //add as you require
            }
        }

        void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // your code here
        }
```