# DataGridView of C#.net

Tags: c#

How to set event when we change the value of DataGridView1. That means when I changed the value of cell, I want to display the text in another cell.

Example : Old Cell value = Nepal
       I am typing on this cell : N
                                  NE
                                  NEP
Every changed of cell value, I need to occur event. When I type N then NE then NEP every changed of cell value I need event.

Comment: I googled the first line in your question and found the answer. http://WhatHaverYouTried.com? -> you simply select the DataGridView, press F4 to see the controls properties, click the Lightning Bolt icon to see the events, double click the CellChange event.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the CellValueChanged event of the DataGridView

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the OP was after the CellValueChanged behaviour. That just tells you, after the cell has been edited, whether the value is different, I think.

Sounds like the OP wanted more immediate events, ie when the editing control's text is changing.

There looks to be plenty of info here: 
[Attaching events to an TextBox underlying for a DataGridView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430156/attaching-events-to-an-textbox-underlying-for-a-datagridview-cell)